# How to always display nav buttons on Lightbox 2?

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox2

Im using Lightbox 2 http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

What i want is when Lightbox 2 is oppened it always shows the nav buttons. 
I tried to look on CSS but theresnt any `display:none` in the elements `.lb-nav, .lb-prev, .lb-next` in fact theres a `display:block` on `.lb-prev, .lb-next`.. I think i have to change something on the javascript but i dont know what.. can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Lightbox uses a simple CSS image swap. Apply styles from the :hover pseudo-classes with this, somewhere after lightbox.css:

```
.lb-next {
    background: url("../images/next.png") no-repeat scroll right 48% transparent;
}
.lb-prev {
    background: url("../images/prev.png") no-repeat scroll left 48% transparent;
}
```

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview

Answer (score 2):

you can also set navigation to true in the javascript file. Also you can add this to the page in which you wish the effect to take place

```
$('a.StockNumber').lightBox({
    fixedNavigation: true
});
```

Comment: I use lightbox regularly and this is how i do it. Look for the word navigation in the lightbox.js, its near the beginning, and set it to true.

Answer (score 1):

In lightbox.js, line 329, change

var alwaysShowNav = false;

to

var alwaysShowNav = true;

Answer (score 1):

On lightbox 2 this worked for me:

```
.lb-nav a.lb-next,
.lb-nav a.lb-prev{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine when I used the css code bellow.

```
<style>
.lb-nav a.lb-next,
.lb-nav a.lb-prev{
opacity: 0.4 !important;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next:hover,
.lb-nav a.lb-prev:hover{
opacity: 0.8 !important;
}
</style>
```

In this code "!important" must be included. Without that your purpose will not be served